Which is the correct date for the commencement of king Hezekiah of the Southern Kingdom of Judah?
A booklet giving a helpful chart on the various kings post-Solomon, says king Hezekiah started to reign over Judah in 715 B.C. On the corresponding chart for the kings of the Northern Kingdom of Israel, it details its last king, Hoshea, as reigning from 733 to 722.
Then, when starting to read 2 Kings chapter 18, I noted that it said:

“Now it came to pass in the third year of Hoshea son of Elah king of
Israel, that Hezekiah the son of Ahaz king of Judah began to reign.
Twenty and five years old was he when he began to reign; and he
reigned twenty and nine years in Jerusalem.” 2 Kings 18:1-2 K.J.V.

However, according to the chart in A Concise Chronology of the Bible, (John D. Brand, p.31, Edinburgh Bible College, 2014), the third year of Hoshea’s reign would be 729/30, not 715. So, which of those two dates is correct, or are they both correct if there were issues of co-regency involved?
As an aside, the Hebrew scriptures speak of the 10-tribe kingdom of Israel, and the 2-tribe kingdom of Judah, Benjamin being that second one, as in 2 Chronicles 11:1. Yet the tribe of Benjamin never seems to be mentioned as that second tribe thereafter. Or have I missed a later verse  about that?

Those dates are approximations and not accurate, it is impossible to have an accurate date because even the Jewish calendar by itself has 360 days for a full cycle.
